# Count rows with multiple criterias

Tags: excel

I have four columns named 'w','x','y','z'.
All can have values 'y','n' or 'u'. A drop-down is provided for selecting these values.

something like this,

[image: excel1]

Now we need to calculate counts according to this data.

1. Count the occurrence of 'y','n', 'u' across 'w', 'x', 'y' and 'z' columns

   something like,

[image: excel2]

2. We also have to count a special condition,

   - if ALL columns 'w', 'x', 'y' and 'z' have value 'n' against it, then [special]=y
   - if ANY one column 'w', 'x', 'y' and 'z' has value 'y' against it, then [special]=n
   - for all other cases, we need [special]=u

Have posted the excel formulas except for one.
Require help in calculating the last scenario.

[image: excel3]

Answer (score 0):

So, for Q2, all done in one cell but you can split them out if you need to:

```
IF(AND(A2="N",B2="N",C2="N",D2="N"),"Y",IF(OR(A2="Y",B2="Y",C2="Y",D2="Y"),"N","U"))
```

[image]